# Кастомный Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Как в Toolbar`e можно менять иконку меню, в зависимости от того, какая страница открыта? Не могу понять, как к ней обращаться, чтобы изменить иконку. Страницы меняются с помощью bottom nav. view.

upd: у меня в toolbar`e всего одна кнопка, находящаяся как menu – справа. Как изменять ее функционал я придумал, это можно делать и без ее участия. Но я все еще не знаю, как к ней обращаться, чтобы изменять ее иконку в зависимости от страницы – вот что мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете написать свой кастомный макет для тулбара по примеру ниже:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Весь контент тулбара -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Сюда вы можете поместить свою иконку.

Как этим управлять?

Тут зависит от того как у вас реализованы экраны.

- Если у вас есть активити с bottomNav и общим тулбаром, экраны реализованы внутри активти как фрагмента, то вы просто создаете интерфейс что-то вроде такого:

  ```
  interface ToolbarController {

      void setIcon(url: String);
  }
  ```

  Ваша активити его реализует, а все фрагменты получают экзмепляр этого интерфейса в методе `onAttach()`

  ```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof ToolbarController) {
            toolbarController = (ToolbarController) context;
        }
    }
  ```

  И где-нибудь в `onCreateView()` или где вам нужно сетить через него вашу иконку в активити.
- Если же у вас там просто активити (хотя я вот не уверен что с bottomNav так можно, так как сам с ним не работал. Но напишу на всяк случай). То тут просто нужно его сетить в каждой активити ручками. Можно конечно инкапсулировать макет и какую-то логику с тулбаром в какую-то сущность для удобства пользования, но больше вы вряд-ли что-то сделаете.